# How to get logged in user modelAdmin callable in django

Tags: python, django

I have this:

```
class SummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'display_user', 'from_till', 'hours_worked',
                    'productivity_status',)
    list_filter = ['date', 'user_crm']

    def display_user(self, obj):
        test = "unknown"
        temp = obj.user_crm

        #if user.has_perm('crm.list_all_customers'):
        if temp.user:
            first_name = temp.user.first_name
            last_name = temp.user.last_name
            test = "%s %s" % (first_name, last_name)
        elif temp.alternate:
            test = "%s " % temp.alternate
        else:
            test = "%s (not linked)" % obj.user

        #return obj.salesperson if obj.salesperson is not None else ''
        return test
```

is it possible to get the logged in user while in the display_user function?

Comment: Can you not pass the logged in user as parameter like this when calling the method in a view: `display_user(obj, request.user)`

Comment: it is called by the `list_display` when trying to display `'display_user'` as a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to use threadlocals to store the `request` object, as it is not readily available in Django at the place where you need it.

Try this:
https://github.com/nebstrebor/django-threadlocals

```
from threadlocals.threadlocals import get_current_user

class SummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'display_user', 'from_till', 'hours_worked',
                    'productivity_status',)
    list_filter = ['date', 'user_crm']

    def display_user(self, obj):
       current_user = get_current_user()
       ...
```